# Why do we need for ParHashMap from Scala while there is ConcurrentHashMap from Java

Tags: java, scala, data-structures, trie, concurrenthashmap

I considered two collections with a similar concept - `ParHashMap` from Scala and ConcurrentHashMap from Java. Both of them have the same time complexity and both of them are thread safe and lock-free, but they only are based on different concepts under the hood - trie and hash table accordingly. And this reasoning leads to question: why do we need for ParHashMap from Scala while there is ConcurrentHashMap from Java?

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is not lock free

Comment: @talex You are wrong - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ConcurrentMap#Lock-free_atomicity

Comment: @talex I think it used to be non-lock-free but that changed in Java 8.

Comment: @ Louis Wasserman `ConcurrenHashMap` always was `lock-free`, but in Java 7 it had an another structure with Node via leveraging a `Lock stripping` concurrent pattern, but in Java 8 it was changed - this approach was disabled and `rb tree` in case of collision would build.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I looked into source code and found `synchronized` keyword in implementation of `putVal` method. I think it mean it have lock. It can't be lock-free and have lock at the same tame.

Comment: @talex `syncronized` block doesn't matter, methods from `Unsafe`, like `CAS`  provide non-blocking features, `synchronized` blocks are one of the step of CHM algorithm behaving. Please check an algorithm of CHM for different operartions.

Comment: It provides lock-free queries, certain lock-free update operations and concurrent updates of different keys. But when performing atomic updates on the same key, synchronization is unavoidable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a thread safe `Map<>` implementation. If you have multiple threads accessing it at the same time they will be in sync.

`ParHashMap` is a parallel collection. If you execute operations here (like `map()`, `filter()`, `aggregate()`) Scala will parallelize it for you (similar to Spark but only within a single JVM).

To summarize, `ConcurrentHashMap` gives the primitive to synchronize threads for concurrency, `ParHashMap` takes care of both sync and execution.

**Edit**: Note that `ParHashMap` is not itself necessarily thread-safe. The idea is to call its methods from a single thread and let the parallelism be handled by the parallel data structure itself.

Comment: @ You said: "If you execute operations here (like map(), filter(), aggregate()) Scala will parallelize it for you" Doest it work similar to Spark parallelization mechanism?

Comment: Yes, similar, but only within a single machine. You can specify a thread pull to be used.

Comment: Actually the inventor of Spark said that he drew inspiration from the parallel collection of Scala while inventing the RDD abstraction.

Comment: But if compare `ParHashMap` and `CHM` without methods like map, filter and etc., only like a thread safe storage of values, are they almost same?

Comment: Probably CHM will be faster. Par collections are in general going to have a significant face lift in scala 2.13. I want to see where they wanna take them now that Spark is in the picture.

Comment: Does `ParHashMap` provide an exactly feature like `CHM` for thread-safe element storing?

Comment: I think your best bet for a thread safe mutable hashmap in scala is to use the implementation from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17542165/1553233. Using the ParHashMap for this is not the right tool for the job (even if you can force it to be).

Comment: Starting with Java 8, `ConcurrentHashMap` also supports several parallel processing methods, see for the methods starting with `forEach…`, `reduce…` or `search…` (or generally all methods having a first parameter `long parallelismThreshold`).

Comment: @Holger, that's awesome, I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that ParHashMap is thread-safe (i.e. can handle concurrent mutations)? This answer says it is not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5926468/14955

Comment: I didn’t say it’s thread safe. Probably it’s not. I don’t think you would want to call this from multiple threads. It kind of beats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. "takes care of sync" made it sound like that a little.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the answer to make it more clear.